# Android - Get the path of the image user pick from gallery

Tags: android

I am working on an android app, in which when user click a button, the app will bring user to the gallery to pick a photo, and then come back to the app to display the photo.

Here is part of my `onActivityResult` callback function:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri imageUri = data.getData();

        //User had pick an image.
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(imageUri, new String[] { android.provider.MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA }, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        //Link to the image
        final String imageFilePath = cursor.getString(0); 

        // imageFilePath is null
```

When running the code, the `imageUri` contains some content provider uri like `content:\\something`, but when I try to get the file path of the image, I got null.

How should I retrieve the image file path that user picked in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is my code and it's work.

```
Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
imageFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageURI));

private String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentURI) {
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) { // Source is Dropbox or other similar local file path
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else { 
        cursor.moveToFirst(); 
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA); 
        return cursor.getString(idx); 
    }
}
```

You will get /sdcard/imagepath ..